# ChaCha20 - How confidentiality is lost if reusing nonce?

Tags: nonce, cryptocurrency, chacha

I read that (key, nonce) pair should be used only once for encryption of a message. My question is how confidentiality can be lost if two peers using a shared key use same (key, nonce) pair to encrypt their own messages (messages of peers would be different).

Comment: If you reuse a (key,nonce) pair with a stream cipher (like ChaCha) you leak the XOR of the encrypted messages.

Comment: Using the same (key, nonce) in a streamcipher means you're getting the same key stream. Breaking those is equivalent to breaking a [one-time-pad with key reuse](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=one-time-pad+reuse).